# Firebase: Is mixing C++ and Objective-C SDK ok?

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, firebase

Is it ok to mix the 2 SDKs? Do you risk having some kind of strange behavior?

C++ Features usually require you to provide a "firebase:App*" when initializing.

As I understood from the docs, you shouldn't initialize an app more then once, but what should you do if you want to use another module with the specific iOS framework?

If you initialize firebase like below

```
[FIRApp configure]
```

and then you initialize with the C++ SDK like below

```
firebaseApp = firebase::App::Create(firebase::AppOptions());
```

you will get a warning, that it is already initialized, so it is detected.

> "Default app is already present, deleting the existing default app and
>   recreating"

But if you just initialize for example the iOS SDK, if you try to get the instance with "firebase::App::GetInstance();" it will return a null pointer. You are not able to use it for other modules. Same goes even if you configure / create your app with a specific name, or if you try getting specifically with the default name: "__FIRAPP_DEFAULT"

Are you required to use only type of sdk between the "C++" and "iOS" one?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase C++ SDK is just a wrapper to the native Firebase framework. When firebase::App is called it triggers the native framework internally.

So before initialising in native, initialise firebase in C++. So it will look something like this:

```
firebase::App::Create(firebase::AppOptions());

if([FIRApp defaultApp]) {
   [FIRApp configure]
}
```

And now when you check for GetInstance() you should not get a null pointer.

```
app = firebase::App::GetInstance();
```

Firebase is created only once by doing this.